# Sonarqube exclusion on Test Data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, junit, sonarqube

Fellow Members,
I am trying to configure Sonarqube on my service.
For tests, I have extracted test Data (setup) into a separate class - `testData.java` class.

My question is, how should I analyse my testData.java using Sonar. Since Sonar mandates all the files under test package to end with `*Test.java`. Therefore if I try to rename the file to something say testDataTest.java it asks me to add a Test to the class.

Since my class is a `final` class and does not contain any test, I have to add a hack to add a meaning less `@Test`.

I would like to understand what are the best practices here and how could I improvise.

An Example of my class:

```
@TestConfiguration
@Import({ TestSecurityConfig.class  , TestAuthentication.class})
public class ConfigurationSetupForTest{
     @Test
     @DisplayName("This is a dumb test so Sonar will not give inclusion errors")
     void dumbTest() {
           assertTrue(true);
     }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please provide some code examples, there are a lot of questions pilling up, as i am not sure, how your testdata class looks like.

Comment: Hey Simon, example added as part of description above